# That watercooler down the bottom left - I want it to do something

Tags: feature-request

This may sound a bit frivolous (ok, it is) and it may be more suited to the UX folks, but with those bright red and blue buttons on the watercooler, my eye and my mouse are attracted there.

[image]

And I really want to see water pouring when I press them...

They look functional - can they be at least partly functional? Water, bubbles...

Just a thought :-)

Comment: And why not. After all Gaming has lasers (or is that Lazers?)

Comment: would be funny if clicking these would bring user to [review page](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review)

Comment: I...never noticed the watercooler.  Or rather, I never had my browser window wide enough to cause it to appear.  (I thought 1200px was enough for pretty much all SE functionality.  I don't know how wide I had to make the window to see it, but it was way more than half the width of my 30" screen here at work, so I assume it's not possible to see it on my smaller monitor at home.)

Comment: weird - even on the small monitors at work (1920x1080) it's visible even when the browser is not maximised

Comment: Honestly, I'd rather have clicking on the water cooler take me to chat...